# How to compare multiple HLOOKUP cases

Tags: excel

In my sheet I have a formula using HLOOKUP to calculate a number based on the content of a cell. The content can be choosen among "OK","NOK","-".

```
Deliverable  | CASE |Description | Value
Deliverable1 | OK   |  *******   |  3
Deliverable1 | NOK  |  #######   |  6
Deliverable1 | -    |  &&&&&&&   |  10
Deliverable2 | OK   |  *******   |  4
Deliverable2 | NOK  |  #######   |  7
Deliverable2 | -    |  &&&&&&&   |  9
```

I want then to calculate, for a given deliverable, the difference between the applied case and the case when the selection is put to "OK". I.e. if I have a `-`, I want to get `7`.

To achieve this I have created a duplicate sheet where I force the content of the cell to be OK, and then I calculate the difference. The problem with this approach is that when using filtering or sorting the calculation is messed up.

Is there a way to avoid using the duplicate sheet?

Comment: Where are you hoping to do your calculation? I would have thought you'd be using VLOOKUP. Have you tried something like `=VLOOKUP(A10,A2:B4,2,FALSE)-VLOOKUP("OK",A2:B4,2,FALSE)` ? Where A10 would be the case you look up

Comment: The actual table I use is more extended than the one I sketched here. But would your proposal also work with HLOOKUP?

Comment: I don't see why not, but I'm confused as to why you would use HLOOKUP, can you share a screenshot of your table?

Comment: I cannot share the original table, but I edited the example in the question to give an idea of how it looks like.